# Accesing variables across all struct in C++

Tags: c++, c++14

Let's say a have a following code:

```
struct Joe {
    const double weigth = 88.6;
    const double heigth = 185.6;
    const double X = Alice().heigth; // Error: undeclared identifier.
};

struct Alice {
    const double weigth = 65.2;
    const double heigth = 179.1;
    const double X = Joe().heigth; // No issues
};
```

In the Alice' struct I can access Joe's variables, however, in the Joe's struct I cannot access Alice' parameters, because it was declared before Alice. Is there any solution, I cannot "google" it anywhere?

Comment: Looks like a job for a constructor. What's the real case for this? We may be able to suggest a better-targeted solution.

Comment: Please do not tag CLion if it does not have anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there exists a solution given that you require that `Joe::X` must be default initialized as `Alice().height` and v.v for `Alice::X`. The very declarations of the classes are dependent on each other and are thus circular.

If you don't require that said variables must be default initialized, you can declare the class `Joe` in `Joe.hpp` and declare the class `Alice` in `Alice.hpp`. In `Joe.cpp` you can include `Alice.hpp` and initialize `Alice::X` and v.v for `Joe::X`.

Example **Joe.hpp**

```cpp
#include "Joe.hpp"
#include "Alice.hpp"

Joe::Joe()
  : X(Alice().height)
{}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make X static const, declare X in Joe but don't Init in sruct. Init Joe::x after the definition of Alice.
const double Joe::X = Alice().heigth;

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand correctly. If I do, are you suggesting to access `Alice().heigth` after the Alice's struct with the static variable X declared in  `struct Joe {};`? It would work, I tried something similar, but my goal was to keep everything in place, i.e., in `struct Joe {};`.

Comment: For creating Joe and initializing Joe::X Alice object must be created, but for initializing Alice::X Joe::object should be created and initialized, so results to circular dependency.
Solution may be found using static members.

Comment: Note that `static` makes for a very different beast. `Joe x{ 16.2, 99.8, 42 };` would have very different, not compilable, behaviour.

Comment: That's correct @Josh. I doubt there's a way to keep the initialization in the struct because if the circular dependency.

Comment: There is probably some template wizardry like [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) that will solve the problem, but odds are good you'll get a result that's less readable. Hard to say without more information on the true problem.